# Xamarin.Mac app that is not visible in Dock

Tags: macos, mono, xamarin, xamarin.mac

I have a Xamarin.Mac C# application that needs to run as a hidden daemon.
How do I tell my app to not show it's icon in the OS X dock?

Thanks!

EV

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can edit the Info.plist file in your project, create a new property on the Source tab of "Application is agent (UIElement)", and set it to the string of "1".

This is the same as manually setting LSUIElement to 1 in a text editor and tells OS X to launch the application as an agent.